# how can I also check if a member has a specific role is an if statement? need the elif to only execute if you have a specific role?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a autodelete message feature in my discord bot and have ran aground when I got to the remove words from censor list command. because the word I want to remove from the list is on the list the msg get's deleted by the bot. I want to circumvent this by adding an  additional if inside my on message delete message event that checks if the user has the Admin role or the Mod role. my desired outcome is that if they do have the role it will return and the msg delete will never execute

````
       if any(word in message.content for word in censorlist):
        if message.author == client.user:
            
            return
        
        elif
            
            return

        else:

            await message.delete()
    await client.process_commands(message)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly 2 ways you for you to get the role, `discord.utils.get`, and there is `guild.get_role`. Anyways here are examples for both

**get_role** (Needs id)

```py
# Somewhere above all the if statements
admin_role = message.guild.get_role(id_here)
mod_role = message.guild.get_role(id_here)
# And then in your elif
elif mod_role in message.author.roles or admin_role in message.author.roles:
```

This gets the roles via id and checks if the member has the roles

**utils.get** (needs name)

```py
# Somewhere above all the if statements
admin_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Admin")
mod_role = 
# And then in your elif
elif mod_role in message.author.roles or admin_role in message.author.roles:
```

This gets the roles via name and checks if the member has the role

**Or it can be done in one line too** (looks bad)

```py
elif discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, name="Mod") or discord.utils.get(messages.author.roles, name="Admin"):
```

This takes advantage of the fact that utils.get returns None if the thing is not found. So it is searching the member's roles for a role named Admin/Mod, if it isn’t found then member does not have the role

**Some even shorter way that is not recommended**

```py
elif any(role.id in [mod_role_id, admin_role_id] for role in message.author.roles):
```

This compares the id role of each role the member has to the role ids of the mod & admin roles